# awk sql parsing

Tags: regex, awk, db2

I have the following SQL used to create a table :

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE"  (
                   "COL1" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
                    START WITH +50000
                    INCREMENT BY +1
                    MINVALUE +1
                    MAXVALUE +2147483647
                    NO CYCLE
                    CACHE 20
                    NO ORDER ) ,
                  "COL2" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                  "COL3" INTEGER ,
                  "COL4" VARCHAR(60 OCTETS) ,
                  "COL5" VARCHAR(60 OCTETS) ,
                  "COL6" VARCHAR(60 OCTETS) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FUNCTION(COL1)) ,
                  "COL7" VARCHAR(60 OCTETS) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FUNCTION(COL2)) ,
                  "COL8" VARCHAR(10 OCTETS) )
                 IN "TABLESPACE"
                 ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

I'm trying to produce an alter table order, using a regex to filter COL6 and COL7, containing both the pattern "GENERATED ALWAYS AS".

The expected text is :

```
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE" ALTER COLUMN "COL6" DROP GENERATED ALTER COLUMN "COL7" DROP GENERATED
```

So far i made this, but I only capture the last occurence :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"; ORS=";\n"}  
match( $0, /CREATE TABLE (.*) \(\n.*(".*").*GENERATED ALWAYS AS .*/, a){
print "ALTER TABLE "a[1] " ALTER COLUMN " a[2] " DROP GENERATED "
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather that using `awk`. If you have access to the database, why not generate the SQL you need from the catalog

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "' || TABSCHEMA || '"."' || TABNAME || '" '
       || LISTAGG('ALTER COLUMN "' || COLNAME || '" DROP GENERATED', ' ') || ';'
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE GENERATED = 'A' AND IDENTITY = 'N'
GROUP BY 
   TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
```

which produces this against your test table

```
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA  "."TABLE"ALTER COLUMN "COL6" DROP GENERATED ALTER COLUMN "COL7" DROP GENERATED;
```

Simple

Comment: I was working with db2look output, but working with the catalog is from far a better option

Comment: Choosing when to do things in SQL and when to drop down to shell and unix is often a tricky one....